# Google Play Console: Remove China, Cuba, Iran, Sudan to make your app paid

Tags: google-play-console

I went to Google Play Console, in the Monetize/pricing and chose the app to be a paid app. The moment I clicked save changes, I got this message:

`Remove China, Cuba, Iran, Sudan to make your app paid.`

I searched all around, but I cannot find how to do that.

Please help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your account in Google Play Console.
2. Select your app.
3. Go to **Open Testing**, and click on **Countries/regions**.
4. Below on the right, select **Remove countries/regions**.